# How do I implement LongPress in a Xamarin.UWP application?

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, gesture, xamarin.uwp

I am trying to implement a custom `PlatformEffect` that will be execute when the user holds down a Control for a long time for my `Xamarin.UWP`. However I found that my application does not respond to mouse clicks. I read that I need to change the `GestureSettings` for the application according to the Remarks [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.gesturerecognizer.holding?view=winrt-19041) to fix this. Problem is I don't know how I can do that for a Xamarin.UWP application, any ideas would be very helpful.

Comment: So, you just want to implement  mouse holding event with PlatformEffect , right?

Comment: Yes this is what I want to do.

Comment: Please check this [code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BasicInput/cs/5-GestureRecognizer.xaml.cs#L135)  that how to implement mouse holding with `Gesture`.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Thanks for this but the code is not much help. I know how to change the GestureSettings, the problem is that I do not know how to change the GestureSettings for a FrameworkElement or UIElement. I made a GestureRecognizer object but the Holding Event is never being triggered.

Comment: Maybe adding some code will make my question more clear?

Comment: Ok, fine I will share all my code that implement mouse holding with PlatformEffect .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I change the GestureSettings for a Xamarin.UWP application?

Derive from official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.holding?view=winrt-19041) , *Touch can produce a Holding action, but mouse devices generally can't.* So, if you want to implement mouse holding, you need use add `GestureRecognizer` for your element and use GestureRecognizer's holding event to implement mouse holding. For more detail please refer the following.

```
public static class MouseHoldingEffect
{

    public static readonly BindableProperty MouseHoldingProperty =
    BindableProperty.CreateAttached("MouseHolding", typeof(Action), typeof(MouseHoldingEffect), default(Action), propertyChanged: OnhandlerChanged);


    public static Action GetMouseHolding(BindableObject view)
    {
        return (Action)view.GetValue(MouseHoldingProperty);
    }


    public static void SetMouseHolding(BindableObject view, Action value)
    {
        view.SetValue(MouseHoldingProperty, value);
    }

    static void OnhandlerChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var view = bindable as View;
        if (view == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Action action = (Action)newValue;
        if (action != null)
        {
            view.Effects.Add(new ControlTooltipEffect());
        }
        else
        {
            var toRemove = view.Effects.FirstOrDefault(e => e is ControlTooltipEffect);
            if (toRemove != null)
            {
                view.Effects.Remove(toRemove);
            }
        }
    }

    class ControlTooltipEffect : RoutingEffect
    {
        public ControlTooltipEffect() : base($"Microsoft.{nameof(MouseHoldingEffect)}")
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**UWPMouseEffect**

```
public class UWPMouseEffect : PlatformEffect
{
    Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer recognizer;
    ManipulationInputProcessor manipulationProcessor;
   
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        var control = Control ?? Container;

        if (control is UIElement)
        {
            var mouseHolding = Element.GetValue(MouseHoldingEffect.MouseHoldingProperty) as Action;
            var target = control as UIElement;
            var parent = Window.Current.Content;
            recognizer = new Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer();
            manipulationProcessor = new ManipulationInputProcessor(recognizer, target, parent, mouseHolding);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetached()
    {

    }
}

class ManipulationInputProcessor
{
    Action mouseHolding;
    Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer recognizer;
    UIElement element;
    UIElement reference;
    TransformGroup cumulativeTransform;
    MatrixTransform previousTransform;
    CompositeTransform deltaTransform;
    public ManipulationInputProcessor(Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer, UIElement target, UIElement referenceFrame, Action holdingAction)
    {
        recognizer = gestureRecognizer;
        element = target;
        reference = referenceFrame;
        mouseHolding = holdingAction;
        // Initialize the transforms that will be used to manipulate the shape
        InitializeTransforms();

        // The GestureSettings property dictates what manipulation events the
        // Gesture Recognizer will listen to.  This will set it to a limited
        // subset of these events.
        recognizer.GestureSettings = GenerateDefaultSettings();

        // Set up pointer event handlers. These receive input events that are used by the gesture recognizer.
        element.PointerPressed += OnPointerPressed;
        element.PointerMoved += OnPointerMoved;
        element.PointerReleased += OnPointerReleased;
        element.PointerCanceled += OnPointerCanceled;


        recognizer.Holding += Recognizer_Holding;

    }

    private void OnPointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        recognizer.ProcessMoveEvents(e.GetIntermediatePoints(reference));
    }

    private void OnPointerCanceled(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        recognizer.CompleteGesture();
        element.ReleasePointerCapture(e.Pointer);
    }

    private void OnPointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        recognizer.ProcessUpEvent(e.GetCurrentPoint(reference));

        // Release the pointer
        element.ReleasePointerCapture(e.Pointer);
    }

    private void OnPointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        element.CapturePointer(e.Pointer);
        // Feed the current point into the gesture recognizer as a down event
        recognizer.ProcessDownEvent(e.GetCurrentPoint(reference));
    }

    private GestureSettings GenerateDefaultSettings()
    {
        return GestureSettings.HoldWithMouse;
    }

    private void Recognizer_Holding(Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer sender, HoldingEventArgs args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("-----------Holding---------");
        mouseHolding();
    }

    private void InitializeTransforms()
    {
        cumulativeTransform = new TransformGroup();
        deltaTransform = new CompositeTransform();
        previousTransform = new MatrixTransform() { Matrix = Matrix.Identity };

        cumulativeTransform.Children.Add(previousTransform);
        cumulativeTransform.Children.Add(deltaTransform);

        element.RenderTransform = cumulativeTransform;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label
        effect:MouseHoldingEffect.MouseHolding="{Binding MouseHoldingAction}"
        FontSize="25"
        Text="Hello" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="100"/>
</StackLayout>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        MouseHolding(() =>
        {
            // do some stuff

        });
    }
    public Action MouseHoldingAction { set; get; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        
    }

    public void MouseHolding(Action action)
    {
        MouseHoldingAction = action;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful.

Comment: A note on this though, I found that this gives false positives from time to time. It sometimes  detects regular taps as a long press (usually when taps occur quickly). Any means to handle this would be great.